# Need to be able to edit a ZIP file in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, alexa-skills-kit

I need to develop an Alexa skill and for the Lambda function i uploaded a zip file(Around 30 MB because the ALEXA SDK is around 30 MB) in the required folder structure(The structure is correct as i tested the skill) . But i am not able to view the file in the inline code editor . If i need to make any changes to the index.js , i will have to open it in a local editor (ZIP all the files in the folder and upload it again) . I will have to do this for every small change i do to the file because i cant open the file in the inline code editor and directly save it . Any help is REALLY Appreciated . I cant keep on reuploading the entire zip for testing out small changes because it is lot of work and consumes insane amount of time .TIA

Comment: It should not be that big. Try this :  https://s3.amazonaws.com/findcontestbucket/node_modules.zip

Comment: Yeah i know its not that big , but if i need to install a request or any other module , i ll have to do npm install <module name> which then sizes up to 30+ mb because of alexa sdk

Comment: You can test your lambda on your local machine. When you feel everything is working fine, then you can upload your code. That way it would be much less hassle.

Comment: This is really a bad design by AWS team. Wasting many precious hours of people on uploading the same things. One should have a virtual machine on its behalf and test it before, but only for big projects.

Comment: Even if one uploads a version every week, it still could waste him an hour to do so. Ridiculous.

Comment: This question has already been answered , but for new visitors there is a better solution. AWS released the [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-command-reference.html), which allows you to test your lambda code locally via `sam local invoke`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the frustration, but zipping and re-uploading your code is more or less the only way to go about doing this. Luckily, the [AWS Command Line Interface exists solely for this reason](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html).

If you've got the CLI on your machine, depending on your development environment, you can simply put the zipping and lambda update into a script. On a unix-based system, it might look like this:

```
zip -r my-lambda-code.zip ./my-lambda-directory
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name my-lambda-function \
    --zip-file fileb://path/to/my-lambda-code.zip
```

Then, whenever you make a code change, just run your new script and watch the magic happen!

[Reference](https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx1UE9W1NQ0GYII/Publishing-Your-Skill-Code-to-Lambda-via-the-Command-Line-Interface)

Comment: Hey Man ,I followed the exact same steps from the reference link you have given me . 
I got the following error :

Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb://index.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'index.zip'

Comment: @AashrithChilkepalli you'll need to give the complete path.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the zip editing on the AWS bucket. It would be something like this:

Define an auxiliary lambda called update_files such that it uses python zip library, and effectively runs the following command:
`zip -r mylambda.zip *` when on `s3://buckets/uploadfolder` (mylambda.zip is on the bucket too). You can then prepare a script to synchronize this folder, run update_files, and upload the zip to the lambda.

This way, all you need to do is update the files in the folder, and you could upload even a single file( as you would need in most cases).

Of course, you should consider security in all of this(s3 permissions, your permissions, and so on).